# how would my array get updated for the next time i run the code

Tags: java, arrays

For example: a user deposits 500, in the array `money[] = {700,800}`,
so its 500 plus the first digit in the array, (500 + 700 = 1200) so next time I run the app the array should be updated and look like this `money[] = {1200,800};`

here is my current code:

the array is

```
static int[] bal = {500,700,9800};
```

this is the function

```
public static void Deposit(int accountNumber){

    out.print("please enter the amount you would like to deposit");



    if (accountNumber == acc[0]){
        bal[0] = bal[0] + depo;
        out.println("Your new balance: " + "R" + bal[0]);
    }


}
```

So how would the array be updated on the next run?

Comment: What are the contents of the array acc? Why are you only checking the account number with the first element of acc? Why not check the accountNumber against all elements of acc?

Answer (score 0):

In order to update information between executions, it needs to be serialized (saved to disk). Java provides an interface for this.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

There are some good examples here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/serialization-in-java/

Fundamentally, you need to wrap your `bal` variable in a class that implements the Serializable interface.

I would note that serializing objects in Java does not encrypt them, so if your application state contains sensitive information, you will need a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

The updated array would depend on the `accountNumber` and `depo` variable.

Let's say that the condition given in if i.e.
`accountNumber == acc[0]` evaluates to `true`.

And let's say the variable `depo = 500`(as given in your example).

So the next time the app runs, the `bal` array would become

```
bal[] = {1000, 700, 9800}
```

This is according to your current code and lot of assumptions on my part.